# difference between using conditional and || in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, ecmascript-6

When something is undefined there are the following two ways of giving a default value.

I have been wondering for a while what the difference between this:

```
return {
   name: user.name || 'Raul'
}
```

and this:

```
return {
   name: user.name ? user.name : 'Raul'
}
```

Is there any I should use over another, or side effects I should be aware of?

Comment: There is no difference in this case. They both will give the same result

Comment: Question was closed, just as I wanted to post this, so I've put it in a fiddle instead: https://jsfiddle.net/8zmfofcd/
Summarized: with the conditional operator `user.name` is called twice, which shouldn't matter in normal use cases, but can make a difference

Comment: @Me.Name: Wow. I finished doing my edit to call that out a mere 45 seconds after you posted the above... :-) Talk about timing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yep, what are the odds :D (although on StackOverflow those odds seem to be significantly greater :p ). Glad someone as well known and respected as you has added it though. I sometimes shy away from mentioning these things, because people tend to reply with it *shouldn't* happen (as you also mentioned, getters should have no side effects), which isn't to say it *can't* happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> difference between using conditional and `||` in js

**Assuming** that `name` is a simple property, then in that particular case, there isn't one. You'll get the same result either way. No strong reason to use one or the other, just your own style preference, and no side effects to one or the other.

But if `name` were a property with a *getter*, there would be a difference: In the `||` case, the getter would be called only once. In the `? :` case, it could be called twice (e.g., if it returns a truthy value):

```js
var user = {
  get name() {
    console.log("getter called");
    return "Ramón";
  }
};

var name;

console.log("Using ||");
name = user.name || "Raul";
console.log(name);

console.log("Using ? :");
name = user.name ? user.name : "Raul";
console.log(name);
```

So if the getter had a side-effect (like the one above), it would matter. (Getters should never have side-effects.)

Similarly, if `user` were a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), its various traps might be called twice.

---

Probably worth noting that in both cases, if `user.name` is `""`, you'll get `"Raul"`...

Comment: perfect, you have answered all my questions - muchas gracias senor crowder!

Comment: @RaulRodriguez: De nada, Señor Rodriguez. Please do be sure to check the update to the answer, though; for some reason, I didn't think of getters at first.

Answer (score 0):

In your case they would work the same way, It is easier to chain conditions in the first way since you can simply do

```
name: user.name || someEmptyVal || 'Raul'
```

while you'll have to nest the condition in the 2nd case

```
name: user.name ? user.name : someEmptyVal ? someEmptyVal : 'Raul'
```